# ClientWebApplicationException is thrown even if custom exception mapper returned another exception

Tags: java, exception, quarkus

Even if the exception mapper is executed and returns a custom exception when I catch this exception it is always ClienWebApplicationException.

So if I do a call with my rest client, and the client returns not successful response this response is mapped to my custom exception by calling my ResponseExceptionMapper.

After exception mapper returns my custom exception I try to catch it in the code, but instead of having instance of my exception I am getting ClienWebApplicationException and the cause of ClienWebApplicationException is my custom exception.

In Quarkus I have rest client

```
@RegisterProvider(IdentityResponseExceptionMapper.class)
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "identity-api")
public interface IdentityTenantsClient {
    @POST
    @Path("/internal/tenants")
    TenantResponseDTO createTenant(TenantRequestDTO body);
```

and

response exception mapper

```
public class IdentityResponseExceptionMapper implements ResponseExceptionMapper<IdentityResponseException> {
    @Override
    public IdentityResponseException toThrowable(Response response) {
        ProblemDetail problemDetail = response.readEntity(ProblemDetail.class);
        return new IdentityResponseException(problemDetail, response);
    }
}
```

and

```
@RegisterForReflection
public class IdentityResponseException extends WebApplicationException {
    @Getter
    private final transient ProblemDetail problemDetail;

    public IdentityResponseException(ProblemDetail problemDetail, Response response) {
        super(problemDetail.getDetail(), response);
        this.problemDetail = problemDetail;
    }
```

For some reason regardless that exception handler maps response to IdentityResponseException, the catch inside the method catches ClientWebApplicationException instead of ClientWebApplicationException

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more useful to throw a checked exception.

```java
public class IdentityResponseException extends Exception {

    @Getter
    private final ProblemDetail problemDetail;

    @Getter
    private final Response response;

    public IdentityResponseException(ProblemDetail problemDetail, Response response) {
        super(problemDetail.getDetail());
        this.problemDetail = problemDetail;
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

```java
@RegisterProvider(IdentityResponseExceptionMapper.class)
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "identity-api")
public interface IdentityTenantsClient {
    @POST
    @Path("/internal/tenants")
    TenantResponseDTO createTenant(TenantRequestDTO body) throws IdentityResponseException;
```

From the microprofile rest client spec (https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-2.0/microprofile-rest-client-spec-2.0.html#_how_to_implement_responseexceptionmapper) you're right. Your exception should be thrown directly. Maybe there is a bug in the resteasy implementation when the thrown exception is instance of WebApplicationException. I am not sure, your solution looks fine for me, but you could try out the checked exception solution. Maybe it'll fit better for you.